# Python prime number checker from a multiplication table ("times table")

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made this script that asks the user for a table.
Now i want to check which numbers in that table are prime.

```
table = int(input("Which table do you want? \n"))
x = int(input("How far do you want the table to go? \n"))

for number in range(1,x+1):
    print(number * table)

print("The prime numbers in this table are:")

for number2 in range(2,x+1):
    for i in range(2,number2):
        if (number2 % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(number2)
```

But now it checks every number between the first number of the table and the last number of the table,
for example:

```
First input = 5

Second input = 5

Result = 
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
```

How can i make my code check only the numbers in the table?

Edit: so it isn't clear for everyone. Let me explain.
I want to make a script that checks if numbers in a table are prime, for example.

```
Input 1 = 5
Input 2 = 10
5*1=5
5*2=10
5*10=50
```

Now i want to check which numbers in that table (1 to 20) are prime.

```
Input 1 = 5
Input 2 = 10
Prime numbers in this table are:
2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 etc.
```

Those numbers aren't in the table, yet my code still sees them.

Comment: If your "table" is a multiplication table, there's not much point checking if each of them is prime.

Comment: @khelwood you could print just the first number if that is prime :-)

Comment: Don't understand the question either... What is your desired output? What does "which table do you want" and "how far ..." actually mean? Note: You only have to check numbers up to sqrt(x) in order to find factors of x.

Comment: Among the multiples of `table`, only `table` might be prime, the other ones just aren't. I don't understand either what you want to do here...

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid your edit doesn't clear things up, at least not for me. You create your table using `number*table`, i.e. there will be all integer number from 1 to 20, in your example above. And then, the loop will check every number from 2 to 20 if it is prime. That's working fine in my point of view, isn't it? What is *not* working yet for you?

Comment: @nostradamus it works for table 1, but if i change the table to 5 for example, it will show me this
Prime numbers in this table
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 etc.
```
But i don't want that, those numbers aren't in the table

Comment: Oh, I see... Some combination of bad understanding and bad communication. ;) Good that we finally sorted it out and @RobBricheno's solution is working for you. Have fun coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a simple way is just to store the numbers in the table and then check if a prime number is in the table before printing it.

```
table = int(input("Which table do you want? \n"))
x = int(input("How far do you want the table to go? \n"))

numbers = []
for number in range(1,x+1):
    print(number * table)
    numbers.append(number * table)

print("The prime numbers in this table are:")

for number2 in range(2,x+1):
    for i in range(2,number2):
        if (number2 % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        if number2 in numbers:
            print(number2)
```

We can improve this using our knowledge of the problem. We know that only the "1 times table" contains prime numbers that are not the first number. So we can solve the problem without keeping track of the numbers at all!

```
table = int(input("Which table do you want? \n"))
x = int(input("How far do you want the table to go? \n"))

for number in range(1,x+1):
    print(number * table)

print("The prime numbers in this table are:")

if table == 1:
    for number2 in range(2,x+1):
        for i in range(2,number2):
            if (number2 % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(number2)
# 0 is not prime, and nor are any negative numbers, so any table less than 1
# does not contain any primes and can be ignored!
elif table > 1:
    for i in range(2, table):
        if (table % i) == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(table)
```

Comment: You could further improve it by only looping through the numbers once and checking each number immediately, and by running the loop `for i in range(2, number2)` only up to `int(number2**0.5)` (which is sqrt(number2)).

Comment: @nostradamus yes but no, because for the "one times table" there are potentially many primes greater than int(number2**0.5)

Comment: Misunderstanding, I guess. You would have two nested loops: the outer one creating the numbers 1-by-1, and the inner loop running from 2 to int(num2**0.5) for every num2 ( =`number*table`) the outer loop generated. But we're running into details, now. ;)

Comment: I still think this is wrong. Consider this gist https://gist.github.com/rbricheno/412273a5738e612c93f4bdf9a08bea60 By not checking if greater numbers are divisors of multiples of 1, you incorrectly consider numbers to be prime when they are not. Also consider the "one times table" to 4. We can see that 1 times 3 is prime, and 3 is greater than sqrt(4). All this really stems from the inclusion of the "one times table" as a multiplication table, which I think is probably... questionable!

Comment: Completely agree. I still think it's a misunderstanding. ;) For every single number to be checked for "primeness" or "primness" (lol), I would run up to int(sqrt(number)), i.e. in order to check 3, I would loop from 2 to int(sqrt(3)), which equals 1 and is smaller than 2, so, 3 is prime. For e.g. number=17, I would loop from 2 to int(sqrt(17)) = 4. Reason for this is simply that there _can't_ be a prime factor that is larger than int(sqrt(number)), because then, this factor was either already checked before or <1 (not integer).

Comment: You would be right if we were looking for prime factors of (table * x). In the case of the 1 times table in this question we are looking for numbers less than or equal to table * x (= numbers less than or equal to x) that are prime. Such numbers may be higher than the prime factors of (table * x).

Comment: @nostradamus I think I see what you're getting at but I need to write down an example and see if I understand it properly, will leave this for now. Thanks for making me thing about this!

Comment: This is inefficient and makes no sense. All the numbers in the table, except eventually `table` itself, are by definition (they are equal to `table` times something) composite, so not prime. Checking them is useless. The only number in the table that could possibly be prime is `table` itself. Check it, and that's all.